# Downloading files using Python

Tags: python

I need to download files from the internet. For that I am using `subprocess` and calling `wget`. Is this the right way? The files are hosted on static links and there is no need to log in or anything.

I glanced over `urllib` but I  could not find any example of it being used to download files of other types.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than what?

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

should work fine for any filetype.  You will often want to specify a filename, rather than use a temp file (the default):

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

There are several other libraries too, but this is fine for basic uses.

Comment: I thought urllib was for getting only HTML files and then logging in somehow. I will admit I didn't RTM.